# c warning: 'struct' tag used in naming

Tags: c++, arduino

My code works on the face of it, but IMHO, warnings are a runtime error in waiting.

Arduino, Slober 4.3.1 compile warning

Much searching to no avail :(

Is it unsafe to let this go?

> ```
> warning: 'struct' tag used in naming 'union frame_t' [-fpermissive]  struct frame_t rxFrame;
>         ^~~~~~~ ..\Array_struct_strncpy.ino:3:7: note: 'union frame_t' was previously declared here     union frame_t  // 4 byte comms frame
> ```

```
union frame_t  // 4 byte comms frame
{
    byte bytes[4]; // access as an array
    struct         // access by parts
    {
        byte sof;  // frame byte 0
        struct     // frame byte 1
        {
            byte adr: 5;
            byte opc: 2;
            byte vok: 1;
        };
        union
        {
            byte val; // frame byte 2 = value
            struct    // frame byte 2 = commands
            {
                byte cmd1: 5;
                byte cmd2: 3;
            };
        };
        byte crc; // frame byte 3
    };
};

struct frame_t rxFrame; // <<< warning?
```

Best regards
Dave

Comment: `frame_t` is declared as a `union` and you're telling your compiler it's actually a `struct` when you're declaring `rxFrame`. So your compiler issues a warning to make sure you're not trying to access a `struct` named similarly, or that you didn't mean to make `frame_t` a struct instead of a `union`. You need to give names to your anonymous `structs` within `frame_t` so that you can access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

> ```
> struct frame_t rxFrame; // <<< warning?
> ```

by

```
frame_t rxFrame;
```

or

```
union frame_t rxFrame;
```

because *frame_t* is not a *struct* but an *union*

Comment: "You need to give names to your anonymous structs within frame_t so that you can access them."

Comment: @DaveHarris no, this is unnecessary, some compiler like g++ allowed that in the past versions of C++ even that was not in the language (to follow C), then that feature was introduced in C++11 definition

Answer (score 0):

Either works OK, many thanks.
"You need to give names to your anonymous structs within frame_t so that you can access them." I built in access as array or by names, so further names are confusing for me. rxFrame.bytes[i] or rxFrame.opc works for me... whereas rxFrame.xxx.opc is less obvious.